# New to creating batch files, why does & work, but multiline doesn't

Tags: windows, batch-file

so I'm new to creating batch files and am trying to create just a simple batch file to create a bootable WinPE USB drive. I have been looking online for hours to figure out why I cannot use multiline coding to create the batch, but can use the & character with the same coding and it works perfectly fine!

I apologize in advance for not being able to figure out how to get the code to show up the way it does in my editor. Also, on that note, I use Notepad to edit my batch files. 
Here's the code that I was using, and like I said, it's super simple.

`echo
:begin
cd C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools
copype amd64 c:\winpe-amd64 & copy c:\winpe-amd64\winpe.wim c:\winpe-amd64\iso\sources\boot.wim & copy "c:\program files\windows AIK\Tools\amd64\imagex.exe" "c:\winpe-amd64\iso" & oscdimg -n -bc:\winpe-amd64\etfsboot.com "c:\winpe-amd64\iso" "c:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso"
goto begin`

However, when I try to make that multiline, so I'm not having to scroll right for ages, especially if I try to create more complex codes, I do not get the same result. Here is what it looks like for me when I use multiline.

`echo
:begin
cd C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools
copype amd64 c:\winpe-amd64

copy c:\winpe-amd64\winpe.wim c:\winpe-amd64\iso\sources\boot.wim
copy "c:\program files\windows AIK\Tools\amd64\imagex.exe" "c:\winpe-amd64\iso"
cmd oscdimg -n -bc:\winpe-amd64\etfsboot.com "c:\winpe-amd64\iso" "c:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso" 
goto begin`

I have gone line by line, entering it in to command one at a time and all the commands work for me if I do it that way, so I know that I'm not missing a file or directory.

Like I said, I'm stumped. Am I doing something wrong? Is there actually no way to execute this batch file in multiline form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copype` appears to be a `.cmd` file,so when it terminates, the batch will terminate as execution is transferred to the second batch. If the line is extended using `&` then the remaining commands should also be executed.

The solution is

```
call copype amd64 c:\winpe-amd64
```

which provides a return location and batch will continue after the `copype` is complete.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I would have never have thought about the copype being its own .cmd file. It took a couple minutes to work out the bugs after I had used your advice (I had silly errors in path names) but it worked!! Thanks @Magoo!

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are not the same! Remove "cmd" from the beginning of one line where it appears in your multi-line format.

Comment: I saw that, and changed it.. I guess it was a result of my many tweaks trying to get it to work. However, even in changing it, it still will not work. @RGuggisberg.

Comment: Where I run into the issue of it not working is after the copype line. It copies those files no problem, but then quits. I haven't figured out how to get the file to keep going after that. I have tried xcopy with the echo f|. I have tried start /wait I have tried start cmd.exe /k ... maybe my syntax is wrong.. but I just can't seem to figure out how to get the second part of the batch file (in multiline format) to work. 
It works fine in the first instance of the batch file with the & @RGuggisberg